# Can't figure out , how to convert PNG to Vector Drawable

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, I saw the solution of converting
PNG to vector drawable(for my app) here, I converted the PNG file to SVG , but on
converting it to vector drawable in android asset studio instead of
showing the calculator(the first one in the second row it shows a black image. Any solution...
here are my screenshot1 [image of icon88 pichon app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01iD7.png)
screenshot2[image of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMRVM.png)

Comment: Don't try to convert png to SVG (which is not truly possible). Instead, find and download the SVG source.

Comment: @momvart I just used the default vector drawables given in asset studio , the one which were resembling a bit to my desired icons.